# Popup blocker in Safari and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, safari, mobile-safari

How does the popup blocker work in Safari and Google Chrome, or generally in any website?

I realize that asynchronous page redirection will trigger a popup blocker but are there any other factors?

I have made amends to my site where, the user submits their details and I show a modal saying "Thanks for using the site, you will be redirected to xyz page" for 5000ms (5seconds) and then initiate `window.open(url, '_blank')`. This triggered a popup blocker in Google Chrome and Safari.

So, now I have removed the timeout and and the new page is opening properly in Google Chrome but is still triggering popup blocker in Safari-mobile.